# Complaining / moaning culture

Tags: scrum, agile

I have a team. We face many challenges and impediments due to a lot of organisational issues which are out of our control.

I am struggling to get the team to focus on what we can control and to have a positive mindset.

Instead, all our meetings are people constantly moaning and complaining about everything and I feel if this small thing is solved we would already be in a good place.

Any tips on how I can get them out of complain mode?

Comment: Can you give an example of the conversations in a meeting? Blocking every proposal with "that won't work because X" requires a different response than "I can't get any work done".

Comment: As written, this isn't really a project management question. It's really more of an organizational culture issue, which means it will likely get migrated to The Workplace unless you add sufficient context to make it a project management question or can explain how this specifically relates to the Scrum framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe in impediments that are out of the control of the team. The team may not be able to address the root causes of those impediments, but there are things that the team can do. I would expect that the team is making the existence and impact of these impediments known to the people in the organization who can remove them. I would also expect the team to look at ways to detect and mitigate the impact of these impediments until they are resolved.

I've also found it helpful to always have one improvement item for something that is within the team's control. Even if the most important, most impactful problems are beyond the direct control of the team, there's usually some problem that the team can fix on their own. Help the team identify and fix at least one of those on a regular basis. It helps the team develop their skills to support continuous improvement and could help keep morale up a little bit until the other issues are resolved.

Answer (score 7):

It would be worth discussing your concerns with the team. Perhaps brainstorm an approach that would improve the mood in the team?

One thing that may also be useful is to differentiate between challenges that can be solved in the team and challenges that need to be escalated.

For example, you could say this in a retrospective:

> The problem we have been talking about, is it something within our power to solve? If not, I can take it away and provide it as feedback to the management team. We can then carry on talking about other problems that we can actually do something about.

Answer (score 2):

When you are facing a problem that is not in your power to solve, then venting your frustration to others is a psychological coping mechanism. It helps the team members to remain sane in an insane environment. So giving people room to rant about organizational dysfunctionalities might not be so pointless after all.

Just makes sure that after they had that opportunity, that you get the discussion back on a constructive path. I usually do that by:

1. Acknowledge the emotions of the person
2. Redirect the discussion from describing the problem to finding a solution.

> Yes, that is a problem, but what can we do to solve it?

> You are correct that our workflow is clearly not intended to work within [process]. But [process] is not in our power to change. So how could we adjust our workflow to better fit into [process]?

> I understand that [tool or process] isn't ideal for our workflow, and that we can't really change either. So how can we make the best out of it while still nominally following it?

> When it's simply impossible for us to work with [tool, process, person], then we have to find a way to work around it. Does anyone have an idea how we could do our job while involving [problem factor] as little as possible?

By the way: You tagged the question as "Scrum". So if you aren't aware already, removing challenges and impediments due to organisational issues should be the job of the Scrum Master. So they should be the person who receives such complaints from the team, looks for solutions and takes care of their implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The problems may be out of your control, but is there any way you can be better about insulating them from the problems? If you are in charge of managing the team, perhaps there are ways you can be working to minimize the effect of these outside organizational problems on your team. You can also raise the issues with the powers above - if you make it clear that this is costing them productivity and therefore money, it's possible that change can happen, or you can at least receive additional support in helping isolate the team from the bureaucracy.

Any of the ways of trying to cover up or compensate for the problems is going to risk appearing shallow or uncaring (trying to distract them with problems they can fix, giving free pizza or other typical corporate morale boosters). It's clear that these organizational issues are having a significant impact on the team, and so any solution that doesn't provide real improvements is only a bandaid.

If, at the end of the day, there is absolutely nothing you can do to actually solve or improve the problems they are complaining about, then it's just as simple as your company sucks in this way, and you're going to have to deal with complaints and possibly even turnover in team members as a result. Keeping records of complaints and exit interviews can help you identify this pattern, which can then later be used to push harder for changes in the system.

Answer (score 1):

Just one note: This could be cultural.

Example: New Yorkers often find bitching and moaning about the things they can't control a bonding experience. The implication is "It's you and me against the world, amirite?" Folks from many other places react to this with fear that the annoyance will be turned against them next.

(I'm not wild about Deborah Tannan's work, but her book *That's Not What I Meant* does have some good examples of this kind of subtext mismatch.)